# How to find n dimensional sphere

Tags: math, geometry

I wanted to know how to calculate\find\generate a n-dimensional sphere given a set of n-dimensional points and if that is possible then what is the minimal size of the such set of points?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: please don't , i really need help

Comment: the minimal size is always N + 1 where N is the number of dimensions, subject to special cases such as colinear points etc.

Comment: Is the sphere you want the smallest sphere containing the points in its interior, or a sphere through the points (which is not always possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very broad question, calculate, find, and generate?

1. To calculate see answer by @YvesDaoust.
2. To find is very open-ended. Do you know they exist? Is an approximate solution okay? Try looking for [least squares of a hypersphere](https://gaupdate.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/l-dorst-total-least-squares-fit-kspheres-in-nd-space-using-n-plus-2d-isom-repr/). Standard least squares for N-spheres is non-linear which can get tricky to do well in high dimensions. I would suggest projecting the points to a N+1 sphere using a N-dimensional [stereo-graphic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection). In which case an N-sphere becomes an N+1 hyperplane, which is a linear problem. Once you find the hyper-plane then project back to N-space to get the sphere. The cost function is not the original N-sphere least squares cost function but I think its worth it to make the problem linear.
3. To generate, not sure I see the difference between this and calculating.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of an hypersphere is

```
(X-Xc)² + (Y-Yc)² + (Z-Zc)² ... = R²
```

Write the equations for `N+1` points and subtract them pairwise. The quadratic terms cancel out and a system of `N` linear equations in `N` unknowns remains (they are the equations of `N` bissector hyperplanes).

Solve it and use one of the initial equations to get the radius.

---

In 1D you use two points,

```
(X0 - Xc)² = R²
(X1 - Xc)² = R²
```

Then by subtraction

```
(X0 - X1)(X0 + X1 - 2Xc) = 0
```

gives `Xc`, then `R² = (X0 - Xc)²`.

The generalization is straightforward.

Comment: but i don't have Xc or any of the centers

Comment: Can't you see that this is the way to compute them ?